# Medium editor insert button - lighter example then the plugins out there

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, medium-editor

Using contentEditable and looking to add the medium style insert button.

This button shows up on the same line as the cursor but then hides as soon as you start typing. It will then show again when you hit return and start a new line.

I have found this for example: http://linkesch.com/medium-editor-insert-plugin/

But the dependancies are huge and I don't need to use any of the existing plugins since my image uploading etc is already complete.

Any help on achieving the same effect as the link provided? Just needs to be a simple button that can be positioned at the start of the typing line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*medium-editor-insert-plugin contributor here.*

We are in the process of rewriting the plugin using vanilla JS (ES2015 to be specific) for the upcomming v3.0. So the plugin will be dependencies free (except for medium-editor of course).

- You can [check it here](https://github.com/orthes/medium-editor-insert-plugin/tree/3.0)
- Also don't forget to read [latest statement about the 3.0](https://github.com/orthes/medium-editor-insert-plugin/issues/177#issuecomment-207261635)

Also, if you do not want to use the plugin and build your own you can still take inspiration from it!

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have started writing my own but not completed yet. Had some luck using the offset values of the cursor position but need to spend the time working on hiding and showing the insert button on new line / when you start typing etc.

Comment: @Lovelock can you succeed in writing your own?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to build your own very simple button for MediumEditor, there has been a lot of work down to make building custom extensions simple and flexible.

There is an pretty good tutorial for how to build a simple button for the toolbar [here](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/src/js/extensions/WALKTHROUGH-BUTTON.md).

There is also documentation that outlines all of the required contracts for a button, as well as the helper methods exposed to all MediumEditor extensions [here](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/src/js/extensions/README.md#button)

Once you've created your basic button extension, you can instantiate it and pass it into the editor at creation time:

```
var myCustomButton = new MyCustomButton(); // constructor for your button

var editor = new MediumEditor('.editor', {
    toolbar: {
        buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'myButton']
    },
    extensions: {
        'myButton': myCustomButton
    }
});
```

You can pass any type of extension into the editor via the `extensions` option, but buttons require you to define where in the toolbar the button should be displayed relative to the other buttons, and that's controlled via the `toolbar.button` option.